# Will my new reputation be "corrected"? Is my anonymous benefactor just messing with me?

Tags: support, reputation

This morning my StackOverflow rep was about 443, then suddenly it jumped to 643 - when I looked it seems that 25 minutes ago somebody upvoted about 30 of my posts, giving me 10 rep points for the first 20 of these.

Is somebody just messing with me, or what? I assume this had to be a single anonymous benefactor at work; will the site recognise that and undo it all?

(At least the whole thing lead to a legitimate extra 100 points because when I came here to ask this question I had to register a meta.stackoverflow account which apparently pays a bonus when linked to a normal StackOverflow account.)

Comment: wow! we need more acts of kindness like this. (i mean or grade inflation. maybe you have a secret admirer?)

Comment: Keep at it.  Thirty will be undone but when you notice just two or three then that's only a [guilty pleasure](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=guilty%20pleasure).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Serial upvotes will be corrected overnight, and bonus 100 here is because you have 200+ reps somewhere in the network, so since you already have 443, you will still get it regardless of the serial upvoter.

And most likely, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798662/eric) upvoted yours, and here is my analysis

- You got 30 upvotes today on answers, He upvoted exact 30 posts and hit the limit since all are the answers.
- He upvoted 40 posts yesterday and got Vox Populi, Suffrage badges, which he probably enjoyed and decided to do it again today.
- He joined the site for 4 days, just started voting from yesterday, so he might not understand the voting system so well.
- You answered his question on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366769/forms-input-default-text/6366945) and he appreciated your answer.
- Your last vote is 1 hour ago, and he has been seen 1 hour ago too.

**Edit**: All of the votes are revoked now, he has 0 upvotes today, and your reputation got revoked too.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that analysis. I wondered if it was that user given it happened around the same as the activity on his question.